# Convert boost array to open cv mat

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I try to convert a **boost::array rightCamInfo.K** to an opencv Mat **cv::Mat K**. I didn't found any functions for this setting so I wrote an iterative approach:

```
float tempK[9];
cv::Mat K;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   tempK[i] = rightCamInfo.K[i];
}
K = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, &tempK);
```

But this is giving me strange results. The range of the given data is between 400 and 0 and the result matrix is around 5 * 10^(-315). So obviously there are some conversion errors. What is wrong? Did I chose the wrong type for the matrix or does this array type is not fitting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `CV_32F` not `CV_64F` and point the first element of `tempK`

```
K = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, &tempK[0]);
```

or

```
Mat K(3, 3, CV_32F, &tempK[0]);
```

Comment: Such a small thing but it works. Thanks. Can you shortly explain why this is making a difference?

Comment: `CV_32F (32 bit)` says the byte I'm reading now is float whereas `CV_64F` says it is double `(64 bit)`.  When you try to read with CV_64F, you try to read a float value as if it is double.